# How to start qemu directly in the console (*not* in curses or SDL)

Tags: terminal, qemu, serial, display, curses

I seem to recall being able to start qemu with only the terminal emulator output, with the graphic window disabled. And here I don't mean with the ncurses interface, that one is nice, but I want the output to flow directly into my terminal, to make cut and paste easier.

I have tried:

```
qemu -nographic binary.img # simply no display
qemu -curses binary.img # nice text output, but not directly flowing in the terminal
qemu -noframe -curses binary.img # same as above
qemu -nographic -curses binary.img
```

I guess an acceptable workaround would be for me to be able to resize the curses console to fit the terminal I am using. Right now it's annoying because it doesn't fit the terminal size...

```
qemu -curses  binary.img



           SeaBIOS (version 1.7.0-20120603_194846-gandalf)



           iPXE (http://ipxe.org) 00:03.0 C900 PCI2.10 PnP PMM+07FC86A0+07F886A0 C900


           Booting from Hard Disk...
           [...]
```

Notice how the display is indented 12 spaces? Annoying. :)

Comment: Use an 80 column terminal?

Comment: I could have *sworn* there was a way to let this flow properly, maybe I don't remember this right...

Comment: i wonder if this shouldn't be merged with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19565116/redirect-qemu-window-output-to-terminal-running-qemu and/or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18098455/redirect-qemu-console-to-a-file-or-the-host-terminal

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6710555/how-to-use-qemu-to-run-a-non-gui-os-on-the-terminal

Answer (score 37):

Old question, but it might still interest people.

Short anwser :

```
qemu -nographic -serial mon:stdio -append 'console=ttyS0' binary.img
```

`ttyS0` valid on most PC. it would be something different on ARM system.

Then the serial port and the QEMU are multiplexed on your output. You can switch between them with `ctrl-A + C + ENTER`.

Long answer: check [this blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20180104171638/http://nairobi-embedded.org/qemu_monitor_console.html), it's awesome.

Comment: Seemed to work without serial for me.

Comment: yes it seems so on latest qemu
it's still interesting to learn you can also to multiplex serial + qemu console on stdio

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't redirect any BIOS output, including int 0x10 output used by real-mode code; you only start getting output once the Linux kernel boots up enough to open the serial port.

Comment: @DavidGiven I suppose that's a matter of what the BIOS code (which is SeaBIOS, not qemu proper) actually *does* with the 0x10 "output".

Comment: You can also add `console=ttyS0` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in `/etc/grub` (make sure to call `update-grub` after) for it to take place automatically.

Comment: @DavidGiven haven't tested but: https://www.seabios.org/Debugging "Additionally, if a serial port is available, one may compile SeaBIOS to send the diagnostic messages to the serial port. See the SeaBIOS CONFIG_DEBUG_SERIAL option."

Comment: doesn't work. qemu-system-x86_64: -append only allowed with -kernel option

Answer (score 4):

Install [SGABIOS](http://code.google.com/p/sgabios/) -- ISTR that recent Qemu versions use it automatically when run with `-nographic`.

Comment: oddly enough, that doesn't seem to be packaged in Debian, so I doubt this was what I was using...

Answer (score 1):

You can update GRUB to pass the required options to the kernel. I'm using Ubuntu 18.04, and I did the following:

Update grub in the guest OS:

- `sudoedit /etc/default/grub`
- Change `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="console=tty0 console=ttyS0,9600n8"`
- run `sudo update-grub`

Reboot guest OS using the following:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 \
  -drive file=ubuntu-18.04-live-server-amd64.img.qcow2,format=qcow2 \
  -nographic \
  -m 4G \
;
```

I recommend adding `-nic user,hostfwd=tcp:127.0.0.1:2222-:22` or similar as an option as well, this will enable ssh connectivity via `ssh -p 2222 localhost` which gives a slightly nicer interface than the console.

The console options are copied from [tldp's remote serial HOWTO](https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Remote-Serial-Console-HOWTO/configure-kernel-grub.html)

Comment: the question wasn't really about how to configure grub, but more qemu. but i believe, as the first answer says, that `-nographic` is correct. thanks for your contirbution! :)