# Cannot redirect QEMU output to terminal using -nographic flag

Tags: linux, debian, qemu

I'm very new to QEMU. So I tried installing Debian in QEMU image following this instruction https://wiki.debian.org/QEMU.

I first created an image.

`qemu-img create -f qcow2 debian.qcow 2G`

Then installed Debian 9.5 from net install ISO.

`qemu -hda debian.img -cdrom debian-9.5.0-amd64-netinst.iso -boot d -m 1024`

I can run it normally with graphics mode.

`qemu -hda debian.img -m 1024`

But when I run it with `-nographic` flag, the terminal outputs nothing.

I've tried several flags including:

`-nographic
-nographic -kernel -serial mon:stdio -append 'console=ttyS0'
-curses`

And more from other answered questions

[How to start qemu directly in the console (*not* in curses or SDL)](https://serverfault.com/questions/471719/how-to-start-qemu-directly-in-the-console-not-in-curses-or-sdl)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6710555/how-to-use-qemu-to-run-a-non-gui-os-on-the-terminal

I know it's running but I cannot see the output. Where did I do it wrong?

Comment: Did you configure the Debian guest to use its serial console?

Comment: No, I haven't. How can I change it?

Comment: Minimal runnable example that just works: https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/tree/753cbe68ff50bea0982e1791c8a2178a999d8377#qemu-buildroot-setup-getting-started Start from there and bisect out your problem.